Troubleshooting Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Dual-Boot Installation Issues
As a beginner in the Linux world, I was very excited to try Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 in a dual-boot system. After downloading the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS ISO image directly from the official website, I faced some difficulties during the installation process.
When I reached the screen where Ubuntu asks me "How do you want to install Ubuntu?", I am unable to see any options to proceed with the installation. This seems to be the only information displayed on this screen, without the possibility of selecting any alternative.
Even before reaching this stage, I was repeatedly interrupted by the message "System program problem detected (Do you want to report the problem now?)". I tried to perform the installation using the "UBUNTU (SAFE GRAPHICS)" option, but the same error persisted.
I believed that the problem could be related to the creation of the installation media, so I tried to create another one using Ventoy, but there was no change in the scenario.
I would like to understand how I can proceed with the installation of Ubuntu in this scenario. Any tips or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

"I am unable to see any options to proceed with the installation" If there are no options, then you cannot install Ubuntu. Consider installing into a Virtual Machine instead of dual-boot.

right, but I really wanted to try a dual boot installation. I just wanted to understand what the problem is, could it be that my PC doesn't have the necessary requirements? Or is the ISO I downloaded from the official Ubuntu site faulty?

You can answer those better than we can. Use the "Try Ubuntu" environment to determine the specs of your PC.  Test the LiveUSB in a different machine to see if it offers install options.

What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Did you use Windows tools to shrink the NTFS partition to make unallocated space & reboot so it runs chkdsk. Is Windows fast start up off? Secure Boot on or off? Should work either way but if proprietary drivers required easier with Secure Boot off. Otherwise you have to create your own MOK - machine owner key to authorize proprietary driver as "secure".

This question is similar to: Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
